# Matlab: Find the result with accuracy of certain decimal place with minimum iterations

Tags: matlab, precision, numerical-methods, decimal-point

I'm using a numerical integration method to approximate an integral. I need to use a minimum number of iterations that give an answer correct to 5 decimal places.

I cannot seem to find a generalised way of doing this. I've only been able to get it working for some cases.

Here is what I'e tried:

```
%num2str(x,7) to truncate the value of x
xStr = num2str(x(n),7);
x5dp(n) = str2double(xStr); %convert back to a truncated number

%find the difference between the values
if n>1  %cannot index n-1 = 0
check = x5dp(n)-x5dp(n-1);   
end
```

This will find  the first instance at which the first 5dp are the same, it doesn't take into account that changes might occur beyond that point, which has happened, the iteration I am looking for was about 450, but it stopped at 178 due to this.

Then I tried this

```
while err>errLim & n<1000
    ...
    r = fix(x(j)*1e6)/1e1    %to move the 6th dp to the 1stplace
    x6dp = rem(r,1)*10    %to 'isolate' the value of the 6th dp
    err = abs(x(j)-x(j-1))  % calculate the difference between the two

    %if the 6th decimal place is greater than 5 and err<1e-6
    % then the 6th decimal place won't change the value of the 5th any more
    if err<errLim && x6dp<5    
       err=1;
    end
    ...
 end
```

This works for one method and function I tested it one. However when I pasted it into another method for another function, I get the iteration ending before the final result is achieved. the final 4 results are:
`4.39045203734423   4.39045305948901    4.39045406364900    4.39045505024365`

However, the answer I need is actually `4.39053`, this has stopped the iteration about 300 steps too early.

Comment: Instead of converting your number with `num2str` you can use `round(x,5)` to round to 5 digits.

Comment: Noted, I've since changed this to a variation of round (as I only have access to round(x), round(x,n) is only after 2014a I believe. I actually used num2str/str2double thinking that it didn't round (I only wanted the first 5 digits eg. 4.39053, regardless of the 6th dp. Turns out this is not the case.

Comment: @user7813820, before 2014b, you can use the normal formulation to round to a given precision: `round2precision = @(x,prec) round( x * 10^prec ) / 10^prec ;`. This allows you to round a decimal number to the exact number of digit you want.